# dart range method

Tags: dart

Instead of :

```dart
if(x >= 0 || x <= MAX)
```

I would like writing :

```dart
if(x in [0..MAX])
```

but it fail.
Does Dart provides something like that ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no sequence generator in core dart as of now. But even if it existed, this would be a bad idea. The `if(x in [0..MAX])` check would have to compare x with each element in `[0..MAX]`, whereas the `if(x >= 0 || x <= MAX)` is just two comparisons.

Answer (score 0):

Use [range type](https://pub.dev/packages/range_type) dart package for that.

```dart
// it will write numbers from 5 to 10
for (int i = 0; i < 15; i++) {
  if (i.contained(5.range(10))) {
    print(i);
  }
}
```